# Can't open header file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a header file called simpio.h, which is in the same folder as the file which is including it in its header. However, I keep on getting the error "Cannot open include file: 'simpio.h': No such file or directory." I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `<>` or `""`? Because angle-brackets could be problematic.

Comment: You need to show your current code attempt(s) so we can better assist you. You are probably using < > when you should be using " "

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use double quotes:

```
#include "simpio.h"
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "simpio.h"


int main()
{
 int sum = 0;
 cout << "Hellasdasdsdadsadsadsasdasdasdasddado\n";
 cin.get();
 sum =  sum + 1;

 return 0;
}


erorr is :1>Linking...
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>Debug\SecondProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Please add your code to the original question, it really makes diagnosing the problem much easier.

Based on my quick Google, it sounds like a linker setting:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14e85604-6929-4707-a22e-8cdf596926a6/msvcrtdlibcrtexewobj-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in

Comment: When you created the project, you should have chosen "Win32 Console Application" and not "Win32 Application".  Only a console application is a standard C program with a "main" function.

Answer (score 3):

You have to know that you should use `<>` when you are trying to include a standard library header or when you want to include a file for which the path is contained in the `Additional include directories` option.

You have to use `""` when you whant to include a file who doesn't satified the previous explanation, let's say that it is almost always file specific to your project.

Some example :

```
#include <iostream>           // library file
#include <boost/thread.hpp>   // there is "C:\SDKS\boost in my Additional include directories

#include "MyHeader.h"             // Local file, at the same place of my .vcproj
#include "Header/AnotherHeader.h" // Local file in a folder named "Header"
```

In your case, we can think that you are in the second case. You just have to do :

```
#include "simpio.h"
```

Or if your file is in another folder :

```
#include "SomeFolders/simpio.h"
```